# Please suggest an optimization in this code without using pow() function ? This question was asked to me in the interview

Tags: c, function, optimization

1. when I give input as num=1, output should be 8
2. when I give input as num=2, output should be 16
3. when I give input as num=3, output should be 32
4. when I give input as num=4, output should be 64
   and so on
   Here is the code

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 


    int main()
    {
        int num,b;
        scanf("%d",&num);
        num=num+2;
        b=pow(2,num);
        printf("%d",b);
        return 0;
    }
   ```

I tried writing my own pow() function, but interviewer did not accept the solution.

Comment: if you always have a base of 2, you can bit shift to achieve the same results as 2 raised to `num`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Karna Rai My advice is never do any assignments in an interview. Interview is not an exam. Entirely ignore firms where there are given assignments in an interview.

Comment: Karna Rai, original code using `pow()` without `#include <math.h>` leads to troubles - too bad you did not point that out to the interviewer.  Not checking return value of `scanf("%d",&num);` is another concern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bit shifting.

Firstly, let's idenitfy the pattern (which you already have, it seems): for any given `num`, we should print out `2` to the power of `num+2`.

Consider that we are working in base 2. (Most) Computers nowadays store  numbers in binary. Consider the binary representation of 1, 2, 4, 8 and 16.

`1  = 0b00001`
`2  = 0b00010`
`4  = 0b00100`
`8  = 0b01000`
`16 = 0b10000`

Notice that for each power of 2, there is only one bit set to 1. For increasing powers of 2, this bit moves to the left. With C, we can achieve getting something like this with the [*left shift operator*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/left-shift-right-shift-operators-c-cpp/) in O(1), computationally faster than the O(log num) or O(num) implementations of `pow` as a library function and your own implementation of `pow`.

Instead of `b=pow(2, num)`, you can try `b=1<<num` instead. This way, when `num = 3` for example, the bit will be shifted three times to get `0b01000 = 8`.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach can look for example the following way using the bitwise left shift operator.

Pay attention to that you should define the result when the value of num (that should be of unsigned integer type) is equal to 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long f( unsigned int n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : 8llu << ( n - 1 );    
}

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int N = 5;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%llu ", f( i ) );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 8 16 32 64
```

Comment: What is that 8llu in function f?

Comment: @KarnaRai Without the suffix the integer constant 8 has the type int. The suffix llu is used to form integer constants of the type long long unsigned int. So the integer constant 8llu has the type long long unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to optimize the `pow()` call, you can't really replaces this with shift operations on an integer type; then there will be lost of precision for high values of n.

However, it is quite easy to write a pow2() function for integer input; It just need to set the exponent value of a double variable (assuming it’s in IEEE 754 format). Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double pow2i(int n) 
{
    short s[4] = { 0 }; // IEEE 754 
    s[3] = (short)((n + 0x3FF) << 4 ); // writing the exponent value 
    return *(double*)&s;
}

double f(int n)
{
    return pow2i(n+2); 
}

int main()
{
    for( int i = 1; i < 201; i++ )
        printf("f(%d): %.0f\n",i,f(i));
    return 0;
}
```